# What type of glass allows UV-B radiation to pass for laundry sanitizing?

Tags: outdoor, glass, laundry

I want to know if there's a type of glass that doesn't filter UVB?
I live in tropical region, and my real objective is for my laundry. I want to hang them out in the sun, for quicker drying, but most importantly, to kill germs. the thing is, I really dislike running all the way from first floor to third floor when it rains, so it would be nice to have some sort of material to "shelter" my laundry from rain, but not from UV rays essential for killing germs.
as far as I know, UV A does penetrate glass, but does a really poor job killing germs. UV B on the other hand, very effective in killing germs, but gets filtered by glass.
thanks

Comment: washing the clothes is a better way to kill germs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quartz glass passes UV-B and is what the tubes of UV bulbs is made of.

But it’s prohibitively expensive for use as roofing material. And rather fragile.

Why not put a UV-B bulb near your laundry? Aside from that the UV rays will cause premature fading of your clothes and maybe blind passers-by. /s

Using oxiclean or similar hydrogen peroxide “color safe bleach” or very hot water will effectively kill the bacteria that make clothes smell dank in the tropics.

Comment: yeah, fading...there's that. dang, no perfect solution for this it seems...thanks for the reply